# Is there an inline assembly constraint for 32-bit immediate for x86-64

Tags: gcc, x86-64, inline-assembly, immediate-operand

Is there a constraint for x86-64 that is similar to the "i" constraint, but that only matches when the operand value fits in a 32-bit signed immediate?

For the function shown below, I would like gcc to use `lock add mem, imm` when the operand fits into a 32-bit signed immediate, and I would like it to use the "r" constraint and generate `mov r, imm; lock add mem, r` when the immediate doesn't fit.

The code as shown works correctly when `v` is a non-constant value or a constant that fits in a signed 32-bit immediate, but gcc generates an invalid instruction when used with a constant value that doesn't fit in a signed 32-bit immediate operand.*

```
static inline void atomic_add(volatile unsigned long *m, unsigned long v) 
{
    asm volatile ("lock addq %1, %0" : "+m"(*m) : "ri"(v));
}
```

I tried using "n" instead of "i" in the constraint, but it seems to work the same as "i".
Removing the "i" constraint works in all cases, but it moves the immediate into a register even when it isn't necessary. Since the vast majority of uses have a constant that fits in 8 or 32 bits, I would rather not use that solution.

Here is an example demonstrating the problem: https://godbolt.org/z/nPY46Kfdh

```
extern unsigned long  x;

unsigned long m(volatile unsigned long *v)
{
    atomic_add(v, 12ul);
    atomic_add(v, 12345ul);
    atomic_add(v, 123456789000ul);
    atomic_add(v, x);
    return *v;
}
```

---

* There are plenty of answers here explaining why a 64-bit immediate isn't allowed in the add instruction, so there is no need for yet another explanation why it isn't supported.

Comment: Have you tried `e`?  ETA: Have you tried `__atomic_fetch_add`?

Comment: @David, thanks, "e" seems to be exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @David, yes, standard atomics are what I should be using, but this code is much older than they are and has never been modified to use them.

Comment: If that codebase does its atomics through wrapper functions like that, you should be find to simply change the function body from `asm volatile...` to `__atomic_fetch_add(m, v, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST)`.  Even if you don't change the other wrapper functions; for x86, lock-free `__atomic` builtins are ABI-compatible with that inline asm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning the comment into an answer...

Looking at the [machine constraints for x86 family](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html) (scroll *way, way* down), we see:

```
e    32-bit signed integer constant, or a symbolic reference known to fit that range (for immediate operands in sign-extending x86-64 instructions).
```

That seems to do what you're looking for.

Also, it appears that both Peter and I belong to the school of thought that says [don't use inline asm](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm).  So whenever possible, I recommend using intrinsics rather than asm blocks.  In this case that's probably `__atomic_fetch_add(m, v, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST)`.

I get that you may not want to take the time right now to rework the entire project to use the newer atomic functions, but it might make sense to start the migration with this one.  Especially if there's a wrapper where you can just drop in the new code.

One last thought: I notice you're not using a memory clobber with the asm.  Depending on how you're using this routine, it's possible you're introducing a timing bug here.  You might want to give it a quick check to be sure it's doing what you intend.

Comment: To be more specific, omitting a `"memory"` clobber allows compile-time reordering with plain accesses, like `_ATOMIC_RELAXED` would.  It is ordered wrt. other `volatile` accesses since it's `asm volatile`, including pure-load / pure-store of other hand-rolled atomic variables.  Well spotted, that's a definite reason to switch over to an `__atomic` builtin unless this mix of ordering requirements is exactly what's desired.